# Preventing express session from setting session id before user accepts GDPR and use of cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

For GDPR reasons I am trying to make express session waits until the user has accepted the use of cookies before it sets the session ID, because now the session id is set straight away.

I am using express, express session and passport.

I've tried using the "saveUninitialized" and set it to false to prevent this but without any luck..

Everything is up to date running on a Mac.

I have a banner where the user can accept the use of cookies and the banner sets a "cookiesAccepted" cookie to indicate that we now can use cookies, so I am trying to make express session waits for that cookie to exist or to set it manually when the user logs in and has accepted the use of cookies.

Here is what is used to set up express session

```
app.use(session({ 
  secret: 'secret', 
  cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, // 24 hours
  resave: true, 
  saveUninitialized: false, 
}));
```

I've also tried to set `resave` to `false` and so on but can't seem to prevent the cookie to set at first load ..

I just want to set the session id when the user logs in, with the passport login function and prevent it from setting automatically on the first page load.

I might be missing something

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell after doing some of my own research, it looks like session cookies are exempt from the consent part of the GDPR laws. [This link has a pretty clear explanation of exemptions](https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/5525-cookies-gdpr-requirements):

> ### **Exemptions to the consent requirement**
>
> Some cookies are exempt from the consent requirement and therefore are not subject to preventive blocking (though you’re still required to inform users about your use of cookies – see caution box below). The exemptions are as follows:
>
> - Technical cookies strictly necessary for the provision of the service. These include preference cookies, session cookies, load balancing, etc.
> - Statistical cookies managed directly by you (not third-parties), providing that the data is not used for profiling*
> - Anonymized statistical third-party cookies (e.g. Google Analytics)*
>
> *** *This exemption is may not be applicable for all regions and is therefore subject to specific local regulations.***

That said, you still have to inform users of the fact that you are using cookies. A banner or a link to a cookie policy on your site will work, as long as the user can access that information clearly and easily from anywhere on the site.

Comment: Many regions have much more stricter rules (like germany). So this is a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this, for situations where it is applicable to the GDPR, then you can create a simple little middleware that makes the inclusion of express-session in a request / response cycle depend on whether a user has had a chance to give consent

(this is example code, its not meant to be copy pasted, but just explain the concept)

```js
let expressSession = express-session ( configObj );

expressApp.use (
  function (req, res, next)
  { if (req.params.userConsentForSession === true || req.cookie)
    { expressSession(req, res, next);
    }
    else
    { next();
    }
  }
);
```